# Installing Pentaho Mondrian and integrating it with custom web application

Tags: postgresql, mdx, pentaho, mondrian

Installing Pentaho Mondrian and using it with custom web application.

I apologize in advance, if my questions seem to be too global, but there's not much info about these topics on internet and I need at least some common answers about overall direction that I should have.

Here's the deal, I have:

1. Some web app (Django/.NET/Nodejs, doesn't matter really)
2. Postgres database

Now I need some OLAP server, that I can run my MDX queries against and get analytics. In this case, **Pentaho Mondrian** OLAP server was chosen.

So I guess, these steps are needed to be done:

1. Install and run Mondrian as a server
2. Connect Mondrian to Postgres
3. Create XML cube schema file via Schema Workbench(seems to be obsolete) or manually
4. Call Mondrian via some API from my web app

Am I missing something?

Questions:

1. How do I install and run Mondrian as a server? Unfortunately, I've only found some confusing and obsolete info about it, even in official documentation.
2. How do I pass MDX queries from my web app to Mondrian and get results back in some meaningful way or form? Is there any API on Mondrian side?

Thank you.